# Punch Clock in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working on a personal project creating a punch clock in java. Since there will be several users clocking in and out I created a `JTextField` where users will type their `ID number` and when they click on the `button(jButton1)` the program should do two things.

1. should go through the column of the database JDBC looking for the ID number and
2. Once the ID number is found the program should copy the current time into the record for clock in or out, otherwise display an error message such as "ID number not found".

This is the idea, I have learnt some things on my own and with the help of google. However, I cannot find this part, any help/direction at all is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to create something like => if 007485378 = 007485378(in database) then copy current time. I have been looking in google but I cannot really find something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform the database operation. Since you are already using JDBC, use `PreparedStatement` and execute your query to fetch result.

If result is found update database with current time, you can get current time in millisecond by calling `System.currentTimeInMillis()`

Once your worker is done its operation, then display the appropriate message to the UI.

1.[How to use PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

2.[A sample implementation for using SwingWorker for database operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset/10623543#10623543)

Considering ID is coming from a `JTextBox`, use `PreparedStatement` like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS FROM WORKERS WHERE ID= ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstml.setInt(1, 007859378);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
   //Extract values from ResultSet
}
```

This way you will prevent yourself from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), also read [how Prepared Statement helps against SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678400/sql-injections-with-prepared-statements)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I think I had seen this option before.

Comment: Hi, don't know if this is the best way to ask you a question. But I have been working on my question and I came up with this idea, what do you think?? 
String sql="SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS FROM WORKERS WHERE ID=007859378"
rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
String id = Integer.toString(id_col);

textID.sestText(id);
textFirstName.setText(first);
textLastName.setText(last);

I am sorry I don't know how to keep the indentation, it does not look good, hope you understand. Thank you

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. Ok I will read what you asked me to read.

Comment: No worries :), glad to be of help